# How to capture netbeans C/C++ debugger actions like start of a debugging sessions, step in, continue...etc

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am creating a application where i am trying to integrate openOCD debugger into netbeans.
I have already created a TopComponent UI to do all openOCD commands(like flashing, halt,resume,laoding to RAM..etc) and also made the netbeans C/C++ debugger to connect to the openOCD telnet session.
However i have to synchronize the openOCD UI w.r.t the netbeans C/C++ debugger UI, for this i need to capture various events of the C/C++ UI debugger like 

**1. Start of debugger  --> inorder to perfrom some startup operations. 

2. Continue button/action, kill button/action ...etc.** 



The reason why i need to do this is that when i connect gdb to openOCD telnet session, the state of the target is controlled by gdb & not by openOCD telnet, so in this cases if user tries to do some openOCD commands (via telnet window like flashing, halting, resuming ...etc) it may cause unexpected problems, to avoid this i need to synchronize the entire UI.

I tried to look into the Debugger API & netbeans CND(C/C++) debugger but to no avail,

Could someone please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Also searching for the solution. I completely dislike the Eclipse.